# jest --coverage show the wrong path

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, test-coverage

[image]

Like the pic above, I move the dir `__tests__` and file `LinkButton.js` from `demo` to `jest`, then run `npm test -- --coverage` in Terminal.
The test is passed, but the path in coverage is wrong.  It seems the jest had cache the old path.
What's wrong with the jest? Waiting online, thanks very much.
GitHub: https://github.com/codelegant/react-action/tree/master/public/src

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked your project and I think you're right. Look at execution times, it's only ~0,5s for one test. Try

```
npm test -- --coverage --no-cache
```

to run your test without cache. Now test execution should take ~23s and path should be updated.